# Does synclock not work on collections?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a multithreaded program where many threads may write to a collection and one thread processes the collection at fixed intervals.

Every few hours the application crashes with an error saying "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" with the debugger pointing to to the method that clears the collection.

Here is the entire code that addresses this collection:

```
Private ui_add_queue As New List(Of Object)

Private Sub ui_add(recipient_id As String, new_id As String, Optional title As String = "", Optional hue As String = "0.6")
    SyncLock ui_add_queue
        ui_add_queue.Add({recipient_id, new_id, title, hue})
    End SyncLock
End Sub

Private Sub ui_interval_update()
    SyncLock ui_add_queue
        For Each item In ui_add_queue
            root.browser.Document.InvokeScript("logblock_add", item) <- crashes here
        Next
        ui_add_queue.Clear()
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Both instances of accessing the collection are surrounded by a synclock, shouldn't this prevent this sort of thing from happening? How is it possible for the collection to be modified?

Also, I've red some other answers suggesting to clone the collection and then process the clone but this isn't really a 100% fix. Even if the odds are small, some data might go missing like that if the collection is being modified by one thread while the other is also working on it.

Comment: Well, you missed some.  Right-click ui_add_queue and select "Find all References".  And beware of re-entrancy, InvokeScript() is liable to have side-effects.  Like triggering an event that gets either method to be called again.  SyncLock cannot protect against re-entrancy.

Comment: Also, consider using one of the types from the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.7.1) namespace rather than using `List(Of T)`.

Comment: @HansPassant I did the reference search, it only listed 2 which are the ones I posted so it must be the other thing which I wouldn't know where to even begin fixing

Comment: @StevenDoggart yeah, I'm using ConcurrentQueue now which seems to be perfect for the job. Been testing for a while now and so far all good.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a different approach, as I also had trouble getting synclock to work.  In my case I did all the collection modifications on my main thread.  I cloned collection contents and passed those to the background threads for safety, then used invoke wrapper and delegate functions on the main thread to perform the change on the collection.

Comment: This is one solution to the problem but I'm more interested in why synclock is failing me in this thread since I'm using it all over the project for all kinds of things and I cant afford quirks.